# VBA copy to another worksheet using multiple if nots

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code in which certain rows in a workbook are copied to a different workbook. The criteria used are if within these rows column F doesn't have a certain value (so not value 1, 2 or 3) then copy.
I can't quite get it to work. Could someone please assist?

```
Dim copysheet As Worksheet
Dim pastesheet As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range

Set copysheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set pastesheet = Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets(1)

copysheet.UsedRange.Select
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Not Cell.Value = "Value1" Then
        If Not Cell.Value = "Value2" Then
            If Not Cell.Value = "Value3" Then
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
                pastesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is the error? Where does it highlight the error as occurring?

Comment: The error is highlighted at 'copysheet.UsedRange.Select'

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the filter option of excel.

Something like this:

numberofrows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(numberofrows, i)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1"), Unique:=True

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,1),Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2,1),...)

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy (workbooks("Nike DRS").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1))

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Base 1
Sub t()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
Dim calsheet As Worksheet
Dim myarr()
Dim myarr1()

myarr1 = Array(1, 2)  'Change the array values which you want to exclude

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FINAL DATASET") ' change the raw data sheet name here
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    Set calsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")

    If calsheet Is Nothing Then
            Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            NewSheet.Name = "cal"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal").Delete
            Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            NewSheet.Name = "cal"
    End If

    .Columns("f").Copy
    NewSheet.Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    NewSheet.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

        For Each cell In NewSheet.Range("a1:a" & NewSheet.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            i = i + 1

                For Counter = 1 To UBound(myarr1)
                    If cell.Value = myarr1(Counter) Then
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                Next Counter

                If IsEmpty(k) Then k = 0

                If i <> 1 And k = 0 Then
                    j = j + 1
                    ReDim Preserve myarr(j)
                    myarr(j) = cell.Value
                End If

                k = 0

        Next cell

    .Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=.Range("f1").Column, Criteria1:=myarr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With        

 End Sub
```